# What would be the most important warnings for new MongoDB user?

Tags: mongodb, warnings, real-time

I start developing first node.js app with mongodb on its back, the app is going to grow into realtime app in some future.

I've been warned that it is easy to take a wrong path with mongo, that the documentation is messed up and so forth.

*So to narrow a bit the argument we may talk about GNU/Linux latest setup and Node.js. Please exclude the discussion RDBMS vs NoSQL. Please include **real life** experience with Mongo setup.*

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

This list is endless but here are a few points.

#### MongoDB is web scale

http://www.mongodb-is-web-scale.com/

#### Always embed never relate

One of the biggest myths out there that is actually supported in places in the documentation.

Instead you should really think carefully about embedding and should probably try to avoid embedding deeper than 2 nested levels since this can make your life hard, especially if you are looking for atomicity with updates on certain elements.

#### MongoDB is completely immune to SQL injection

Not true, you can make a MongoDB query behave in a manner it is not supposed: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#how-does-mongodb-address-sql-or-query-injection

#### Stored Procedures

MongoDB has no sense of this instead it relies on your designing your database in such a manner to avoid micro-optimisations like this.

So each time you: http://dirolf.com/2010/04/05/stored-javascript-in-mongodb-and-pymongo.html you are killing a kitten (especially with `eval`), stop killing teh kittenz.

#### JOINs

None of that here, stop trying to do it via Map Reduce already and just learn NoSQL.

#### Working Set and Memory management

Beaware of what you are shoving into memory and how the LRU works. MongoDB does NO memory management of its own. Beaware that MongoDB uses `mmap` to memory map your data.

#### The official list

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Gotchas

This is also a gotcha since some of these points are actually wrong:

> You cannot shard an existing collection over 256G.

This applies to old MongoDBs only.

Comment: Ohh, thank you! A lot to read! I'm interested only in new setups.

Comment: @Igor I could probably write an entire 200 page white paper on my own gotchas about setting up MongoDB in production, this question is too broad to be able to with that amount of detail

Comment: If one day you would, I'll be the first to buy the book of yours. Let me mention your blog here: http://sammaye.wordpress.com/category/web-development/mongodb-web-development/

Answer (score 0):

I found that when using Mongo, i had to think 'outside' of my normal database schema design. You shouldn't try to force your prior knowledge of databases onto Mongo.

I know you mention to exclude RDBMS vs NoSQL, but i feel this is a valid point anyway.

Be open to change :-), Once i started doing that Mongo seemed to feel natural to me. I actually love the flexibility of it.

Don't make workarounds to fit Mongo, Do it the Mongo way, and you will find it alot easier.

Comment: Ok, thank you for sharing! Have you encountered some caveats with mongo, that is cashes, difficulty with recovering from crashes? And from your answer I see there exist a Mogo-way? Could you elaborate a bit please.

Comment: No problem, I actually haven't went into production with it just yet. Hopefully will be shortly :-) Well, it's really just NoSql schema design, so it doesn't support joins. Which means you need to think a different way for your data. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling/#data-model-large-number-of-collections